# why is it sometimes printing "Correct!" two times and not accepting the input?

Tags: python

'''I was writing the code for 'Hangman game'. But it's printing "Correct!" two times and not getting why...please tell where's the problem
'''

```
import random

def rand_word():

    fp=open("30.txt","r")
    list=fp.readlines()
    random_word=random.choice(list)
    return random_word
    fp.close()

def game(list):

    done=len(list)
    correct=0
    while correct!=done:
        letter=input(("Guess a letter: "))
        for i in range(done):
            if letter==list[i]:
                print("Correct!") #this line is unexpected being printed two times sometimes
                correct+=1          

    print("The word was {}".format(str(list)))

if __name__=="__main__":

    random_word=rand_word()
    list=list(random_word.lower())
    list.remove(list[len(list)-1])
    print(list)
    print("Welcome to Hangman Game!!")
    game(list)
```

Comment: Is it happening when a letter is in the word twice? It looks like you're iterating through the length of the list i.e. `1 - len(list)` and if, for instance, `i= "o"` and the word is `stackoverflow`, it would return "correct" twice since it's in index 5 and index 11

Comment: @WStokvis yeah i just got it...i couldn't see it previously..thank you!

Comment: if you get stuck in a situation like this, it helps to retrace your steps. Find an instance where it's printing correct twice and then write some code that will print "incorrect" if your `if` statement fails. You would see each check happen and start seeing a pattern as to why it's failing.

Comment: Re: your deleted question, I'll post this here. I was writing an answer when you deleted it: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/bb51308526ec4bcb43f44ffcdd5d13c2

Comment: yes! Actually i spent hours for it yesterday! and now people were suggesting type conversions there..which i think i'd tried! and i felt i did mistakes while posting questions so i was not seeming to be professional.But the reason is I've never used such sites..so i deleted as i didn't want to sound silly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but thank you...if i don't get it working by tomorrow by myself..I'm definitely gonna refer your solution.

Comment: @user10058776 The issue with your question was that I basically said "here's a bunch of code that's not working. Why isn't it working?", which is very difficult to answer when we don't even know what it's supposed to be doing. Just make sure you've provided enough information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @user10058776 And if I had to guess why your conversion attempt didn't work, I'd guess that you tried to convert the entire user input into a single number instead of a list of numbers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand! I'll take care of the things while posting next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening in the case where you have 2 occurences of a letter. A quick fix would be to add a flag to see if you've already found the letter, like such:

```
while correct!=done:
    letter=input(("Guess a letter: "))
    found = False
    for i in range(done):
        if letter==list[i]:
            if not found:
                print("Correct!") #this line is unexpected being printed two times sometimes
                found = True
            correct+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the letter is two times in the word, since random_word.lower() might produce words with duplicate letters. If you don't want this, simply add a break statement after the print statement to stop the for loop after one hit.

Comment: you'd also need to adjust the condition on the while loop, as it will no longer work if you break out of the for loop